# how to get key on server that retrofit2 sents

Tags: php, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to get key in php of @POST that retrofit sents in android.

This is my code

Java

```
public interface GetUser{

    @POST("tronecity/signup.php")
    Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
}
```

PHP

```
echo json_decode($_POST['body']);
```

other i get error : body in $_POST is not defined

Comment: try `print_r($_POST)` to lookup the post data. You'll be able to check all the data being set in post request.

Comment: That a answer : Array ( )